# Unable to import text column data contained in separate lines

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have raw data in this txt format:

```
Name|Occupation|Comment
Robert|Doctor|To process, please provide:
a. Tax Returns
b. Identification
c. Statement of Approval
Sally|Accountant|Approved
```

Here, `|` is the delimiter.

For Robert, I want "To process, please provide: a. Tax Returns b. Identification c. Statement of Approval" to be reflected as one string under `Comment`.

However, using `read.csv` to import with the following arguments:

```
read.csv(
    "data/text_data",
    fileEncoding = "UTF-8",
    sep = "|",
    na.strings = "",
    quote = ""
  )
```

gives me additional rows where

```
Name                        Occupation    Comment
Robert                      Doctor        To process, please provide:
a. Tax Returns              NA            NA
b. Identification           NA            NA
c. Statement of Approval    NA            NA
Sally                       Accountant    Approved
```

Are there any R import functions or wrangling tricks to fix this? Tidyverse solution is highly preferred, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easy option splitting the data on a temporary `"id"` column using `by`, apply transformations and recombine. For convenience you may wrap this in a function.

```
myDataReader <- \(link) {
  r <- read.csv(link, fileEncoding="UTF-8", sep="|", na.strings="", quote="")
  r$id <- cumsum(!is.na(r$Occupation))
  do.call(what=rbind, by(r, r$id, \(x) {
    cbind(x[1, 1:2], Comment=trimws(paste(x[1, 3], toString(x[-1, 1]))))
  }))
}

myDataReader('data/text_data')
#     Name Occupation                                                                                 Comment
# 1 Robert     Doctor To process, please provide: a. Tax Returns, b. Identification, c. Statement of Approval
# 2  Sally Accountant                                                                                Approved
# 3    Tom     Lawyer                           To process, please provide: a. Tax Returns, b. Identification
# 4  Sally Accountant                                                                                Approved
```

**Note:** R>= 4.1 used.

---

*Content of `'data/text_data'`:*

```
Name|Occupation|Comment
Robert|Doctor|To process, please provide:
a. Tax Returns
b. Identification
c. Statement of Approval
Sally|Accountant|Approved
Tom|Lawyer|To process, please provide:
a. Tax Returns
b. Identification
Sally|Accountant|Approved
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf - do you happen to have a tidyverse solution as well?

Comment: @Desmond Unfortunately no, I do not work with tidyverse. But if you need  convenience you may wrap this in a function, please see updated answer.